# What is the 以 in 给人以？

Tags: meaning

‘给人以’ is a common phrase. I think this ’以‘ works like ’而‘ to give a sense of 'cause'. Can I replace ’以‘ with ’而‘ in 1.:

1. 给人以诚恳、自信的印象

浴室给人以明亮通风之感。
这座桥无法给人以美的享受。

为某事而受苦
因某事而出名

[zdic](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/4EE5.htm) 6. 文言连词，与“而”用法相同：梦寐～求。

Comment: 给NP1以NP2  give NP1 NP2, give NP2 to NP1, examples from bkrs, 给人以强烈印象,给人以温柔感觉的黑夜,给人以假象
give a false impression
改
给人以说闲话的口实
set tongues wagging
改
给人以攻击自己的口实
give sb. a handle against oneself
改
给人以极大的享受
give keen enjoyment

Comment: also see previous Q＆A，What is the function and/or meaning of the 2 '以‘ in this phrase?  （而 cannot replace 以）

Answer (score 1):

以 here works like 'with', not 'cause'.

In your examples, these '以' can't be replaced with '而', but can be ommited.

Comment: So '给人以诚恳、自信的印象' should be 'give a person with  honest, confident impression'??

Comment: @Pedroski  In this case, "给人以sth" means "give sth. to people", it's a variant of "以sth给人" in ancient Chinese. A more general pattern is "V a 以 b"(= 以 b V a) where 以 serves as 把、用. You can see the same pattern in 授人以渔、嗤之以鼻、杀人以梃与刃 and 以德报怨、以卵击石、以身殉职, etc.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, it's more like the definition 8 in [zdic](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/4EE5.htm):

> 8. 用在动词后，类似词的后缀：可～。得～。

Think about the words: 给以 and 予以. In this case, you just add a person in the middle of 给以. So, you can ignore 以 when you translate it into English.